# transform data.frame for Market Basket Analysis in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I am trying to do Market Basket Analysis with R and run into a problem. I use .csv file, where are two columns "Product" and "Customer". Customer number is repeated as many times as he purchased different products. The table looks like that:

```
Product Customer    
114  1    
112  2    
112  1   
113  4    
115  3    
113  2   
111  2    
113  3
```

And I need to make it like this: (two columns: customer, products. For every customer all the products he bought in one cell).

Customer Products

```
1 114, 112    
2 112, 113, 111    
3 115, 113    
4 113
```

What should I do?

Any help would be great!

Comment: In base R, `aggregate`... Or any of your favorite aggregation tools... "data.table", "dplyr", ...

Comment: This question is being asked over and over and over again and I still can't find a canonical dupe for this

Comment: @DavidArenburg, But none of the answers so far have used `toString`!!! We should add an answer! :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto just wait for it.... Yesterday I saw `%in%`, `intersect` and `match` in 3 different answers while each thinks he is more original than others. <sigh>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` (`df` contains your original data frame):

```
aggregate(Product~Customer, df, paste, sep = ", ")
#   Customer       Product
# 1        1      114, 112
# 2        2 112, 113, 111
# 3        3      115, 113
# 4        4           113
```

or `dcast` depending on what you want the output to look like:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(transform(df, count = 1), Customer~Product, fill = 0)
#   Customer 111 112 113 114 115
# 1        1   0   1   0   1   0
# 2        2   1   1   1   0   0
# 3        3   0   0   1   0   1
# 4        4   0   0   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is

```
Product <- c(114,112,112,113,115,113,111,113)
Customer <- c(1,2,1,4,3,2,2,3)
df <- data.frame(Product,Customer)
```

you can use `tapply` (without the >)

```
> tapply(df$Product,df$Customer,list)

$`1`
[1] 114 112

$`2`
[1] 112 113 111

$`3`
[1] 115 113

$`4`
[1] 113
```